# what's wrong with runif (or maybe me) in R?

Tags: r, random

I am trying to generate a random variable from uniform distribution that also depends on random variable.

Ideally, I want `z2` to be a random variable as well.

For example,

```
set.seed(123)
#generate first random variable z1
z1 <- runif(10,0,1)
#generate secondrandom variable z2
z2 <- ifelse(z1>= 0.7, runif(1,0.6,0.9), runif(1,0.2,0.5))
df <- data.frame(z1,z2)
```

But if you look at `z2` it contains only two levels.

```
          z1        z2
1  0.2875775 0.3360002
2  0.7883051 0.8870500
3  0.4089769 0.3360002
4  0.8830174 0.8870500
5  0.9404673 0.8870500
6  0.0455565 0.3360002
7  0.5281055 0.3360002
8  0.8924190 0.8870500
9  0.5514350 0.3360002
10 0.4566147 0.3360002
```

We can generate 1000 number and summarize the results.

```
set.seed(123)
#generate first random variable z1
z1 <- runif(1000,0,1)
#generate secondrandom variable z2
z2 <- ifelse(z1>= 0.7, runif(1,0.6,0.9), runif(1,0.2,0.5))

table(df$z2)

0.352099318057299 0.655542095610872 
              707               293
```

Comment: It is the recycling rule: `runif(1,0.6,0.9)` is expanded to a vector with the same length as `z1>=0.7` in the construct `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate `z2` using vectorized method. Therefore, when you use `runif(1 ,0.6,0.9)`, you actually pulling only one number. However, if you'll do `runif(length(z1) ,0.6,0.9)`, you'll pull the length of z1.

```
set.seed(123)
#generate first random variable z1
z1 <- runif(1000,0,1)
#generate second random variable z2
z2 <- ifelse(z1 >= 0.7, runif(length(z1) ,0.6,0.9), runif(length(z1),0.2,0.5))

df <- data.frame(z1,z2)
table(df$z2)
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by a brief explanation of why you need to do that to generate `z2` properly.

Comment: Thanks, @DJV! this seems to work... any reason of why?

Comment: @Marius and  user9292, Sorry, it took me time  to write it. Please see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `runif(1,0.6,0.9)` and `runif(1,0.2,0.5)` functions have only been run once. They don't run each time you compare `z1` to 0.7. Therefore, you end up with only two values for `z2`.

You could consider to use `replicate` to run the `runif` functions each time again. UPDATE: or `length(z1)` like @DJV proposed.

Comment: even if i removed the seed. it will still be two levels--- but each run will generate two new levels.